# Why does my sliding effect not work as expected in my react application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

What i want is a normal e-commerce sliding effect when clicking on the cart symbol. In my react application, I use a state to control the display of my cart such that onClick, state will be true and cart will display without any animation.

Now i would like to add animation using `transform: translateX(100%)`. Upon clicking my cart symbol nothing is being displayed instead. I used devtools to examine what happen and upon unchecking the `transform` attribute, what i wanted appear but when checking it again it displayed nothing. I am not sure whats happening, please help!

Below is the component that is controlling the state of displaying the cart component.
The `onClick` function will switch the state of `open` to true.

```
{open ? (
   <Elements stripe={stripeTestPromise}>
      <Cart open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
   </Elements>
 ) : null}
```

In my cart component, this is a snippet of the code

```
<div className="cart__container">
      <div className="cart__wrapper">
        <div className="cart__header">
          <h1>Your Cart</h1>
          <p className="close--icon" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            x
          </p>
        </div>

//other codes

</div>
```

And this is my css for the cart component top level `cart__container`

```
.cart__container{
  width: 550px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 300ms ease 0s;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

translateX moves it to the right, so when its set to 100%, its off the screen to the right, setting translateX back to 0 would cause it to reappear, flushed to the right edge of the screen. You need set a toggle which switches the translateX value from 100% (hidden) to 0% (present)

Comment: How do i use the current state ```open``` to do that? Is it possible? Cuz right now this state is the one controlling the display of the cart? Is it possible to add this transition functionality with it?